# Webstorm typescript single file compilation

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a typescript module split over two files in Webstorm. I want to compile it into a single javascript file. However, when it is compiled, only one or the other typescript file has been compiled (it is not merging them, and probably overwriting one with the other). I will only see the methods from aClass OR bClass but not both. What settings are required to get the typescript module over 2 files merged and compiled into a single file?

Under Languages and Frameworks I have the following settings:

> Command line options: --module amd --sourcemap $FileName$ --out
>   script.js
>
> Use output path: /public/Script

My typescript files are:

aClass.ts

```
module aModule{
  export class aClass implements IInterface{
      //Some methods
  }
}
```

bClass.ts

```
module aModule{
  export class bClass implements IInterface{
      //Some methods
  }
}
```

IInterface.ts

```
module aModule {
  export interface IInterface {

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set 'Compile main file' option and specify a file name in the 'Output path' field + you need to specify in /// all referenced files.

The second way is to use 'tsconfig.json' as was suggested.

Answer (score 2):

> --module amd --sourcemap $FileName$ --out script.js

You cannot use `--module` and `--out` together. The compiler should error but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I found what you mean under "Trade-offs for External Modules" on this page: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript

Comment: However, after removing the --module part, I am still only getting a single class exported into my script.js

Comment: Because webstorm is not passing in all the files. ... just the current one. Setup your webstorm config to pass in *all the files*